# Start Android activity 'manually'

Tags: android, android-activity

Is it possible to maintain app lifecycle with my code.
I mean to create and control activity ctreation.
Maybe my Windows programming experience mess my Android programming attempts.
For example I want to have list of started activities and to start new activity using code in my application class. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "I want to have list of started activities"

**=** It's managed by Android as [Activity Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

> "to start new activity using code in my application class"

**=** possible using [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, RequiredActivity.class);
 startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

hope this will help...